# How Do I Determine Why Hard Drives Won't Spin Down?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-management

I run a dual boot setup with both Windows and macOS; under macOS I use two external USB drives in a mirrored RAID storing a lot of bulk data with redundancy, these are formatted as Apple RAID devices.

Naturally, under Windows these devices serve no purpose as I have no drivers for Apple RAID (if any even exist), so I would expect the drives to simply spin down according to my system's 10 minute setting for idle drives, as they shouldn't be in use by Windows since nothing but the EFI partitions are supported.

However, this isn't the case, as the drives remain spinning; a fact I hadn't noticed at all since they're so quiet when they aren't writing data, but which I noticed by chance when I saw the operating lights (they're a bit hard to see as the drives are hidden away).

Now, while I would appreciate any advice on how I might force Windows to ignore these drives so they will power down, my real question is; how do I determine **why** they aren't spinning down at all? It seems strange that drives with nothing on them that should be of interest to Windows are being kept "active" by Windows, there must surely be a reason.

I should add, I have another drive, again formatted for Mac but just as a plain HFS+ volume, and this powers down just fine after initially being active on startup, so the idle-time feature seems to be working just fine for that one.

Here is the `Power data` properties for one of the two identical drives:

```
Current power state:
D3

Power capabilities:
00000019
PDCAP_D0_SUPPORTED
PDCAP_D3_SUPPORTED
PDCAP_WAKE_FROM_D0_SUPPORTED

Power state mappings:
S0 -> D0
S1 -> D2
S2 -> D2
S3 -> D2
S4 -> D2
S5 -> D3
```

Comment: Do the drives spin down if you take them offline in the Disk Management MMC snap in? Also, what power states does Windows show the drives support? That can be found in Device Manager, your drive's properties, details tab, supported power states item. Please [edit] the info into the question.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Disabling the devices in Device Manager does indeed cause them to power off, thanks! I didn't see a "supported power states" item but I'm putting the contents of "Power data" into the question, as it seems like it may be what you're asking for.

Comment: You're correct, it was the `Power data` item (I typed that from memory...oops!).

Comment: For clarification, did you get the Power data *after* disabling the device? I ask because the current power state D3 means "off."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disable the disk to force it to power off

Since you don't use these drives in Windows, you can force them to *always* be in a powered off state by disabling them in Device Manager. This has the added benefit of the drives being powered off as soon as Windows starts instead of waiting until an inactivity timer expires.

#### Who's responsible for powering off the device?

> ...My real question is; how do I determine why they aren't spinning down at all?

According to the Microsoft doc [Managing Device Power Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/managing-device-power-policy) it is the responsibility of the driver that "knows the most" about the device to manage its power state:

> ...One driver in the device stack for each device maintains and
> administers power policy for the device. This driver is the device
> power policy owner for the device. The device power policy owner is the driver that has the most information about the device usage and power state.

Usually this is the main device driver (the ["function" driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/function-drivers)) for the device:

> Typically, the function driver for a device is its power policy owner, although for some devices another driver or system component might assume this role.

These other device drivers would be a [bus driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/bus-drivers) or much less likely, a [filter driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/filter-drivers).

It seems then that the responsible driver is not properly managing the disk's power state. This conclusion is strengthened by the observation that normal Windows processes are unlikely to be accessing the disks since they have no data partitions. Troubleshooting this problem is made more complicated due to the involvement of the USB bus, as the drivers responsible for that bus also come into play for the power management question.

You can try different drivers (if any are available) and see if that has any effect. Beyond that, you could either raise a bug report with the device manufacturer, or disable the disk in Device Manager and be done with it!